# Drupal 8 always editing a translation, never the original

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a website with 4 languages, while English is the default. Each language has its own directory (`mydomain.com/contact`, `mydomain.com/jp/contact`, etc.). I have the following languages:

- English
- Czech
- Japanese
- Russian

For the record, my language detection is configured with these priorities:

1. URL
2. Session
3. Selected Language
4. Browser

When I try to edit a translation of a content page (let's say Japanese), it works just fine, but when I try to open an edit page (`mydomain.com/node/6/edit`) of the orignal, english node, I'm always getting "Edit Basic Page Nobg Kontakty [Czech translation]", with the Czech content and can't access the edit page for the english original. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use English as default without URL prefix you have to disable

- Session
- Browser

in the language detection list, so that only URL and Selected Language (which can't be removed) is enabled.

Then configure in

- Selected Language

the site's default language (English).